# I am confused about how to add values in the Other section

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary, if-statement

> Write a python program that will make a dictionary from the given list of
> Student IDs based on the department and admitted year.
> ID explanation:
> First 2 digits: Year
> 4th and 5th digit: Department 01 = CSE, 41=CS, 21=EEE, Any other digits = Other
> For example, ID: 21121347, in this ID, the first 2 digits are 21. So the
> year is 2021.
> The 4th and 5th digit are 21. So the department in EEE.
> Given List [Your code should work for all types of similar IDs if the given
> List is changed.]:
> IDs =
> ['20201199','21121347','20141052','20341121','21241369','21272199','19241187','19101007','20101035', '21121875', '19141534', '19301552', '21141135', '21365001']
>
> Sample Output (You have to print the resultant dictionary only)

```
{
     2020:{
              'CSE': ['20201199', '20101035'],
              'CS': ['20141052', '20341121']
              },
     2021:{
              'EEE': ['21121347', '21121875'],
              'CS': ['21241369', '21141135'],
              'Other': ['21272199', '21365001']
              },
     2019:{
              'CS': ['19241187', '19141534'],
              'CSE': ['19101007', '19301552']
             }
}
```

My Code:

```
IDs = ['20201199','21121347','19101052','19301121','20221369','21241199','19241187','20141007','20101035', '21121875', '19141534', '20341552', '20121135', '21341001']

dct = {}
dptname = {'01':'CSE','41':'CS', '21':'EEE', "Other": }
for idx in IDs:
    yr = '20' + idx[:2]
    dpt = dptname[idx[3:5]]
    if yr in dct:
        if dpt in dct [yr]:
            dct[yr][dpt].append (idx)
        else:
            dct[yr][dpt] = [idx]
    else:
        dct[yr] = {dpt : [idx]}

print (dct)
print ()
```

I am mainly confused how to add to the Other in dictonary

Comment: Remove 'Other' from the `dptname` dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if idx[3:5] matches one of the dictionary keys - if not use "Other" as a key:

```
IDs = ['20201199','21121347','19101052','19301121','20221369','21241199','19241187','20141007','20101035', '21121875', '19141534', '20341552', '20121135', '21341001', '21272199', '21365001']

dct = {}
dptname = {'01':'CSE','41':'CS', '21':'EEE'}
for idx in IDs:
    yr = '20' + idx[:2]
    if idx[3:5] in dptname.keys():
        dpt = dptname[idx[3:5]]
    else:
        dpt = "Other"
    if yr in dct:
        if dpt in dct [yr]:
            dct[yr][dpt].append (idx)
        else:
            dct[yr][dpt] = [idx]
    else:
        dct[yr] = {dpt : [idx]}

print (dct)
print ()
```